# Override quicktabs tab titles

Tags: blocks

I have a quicktabs instance that shows lists of content by year (2012, 2011, 2010 and so on). Each tab is a views generated block that pulls content by date using relative values (current year, current year-1, etc.). How can I override the title of each of the tabs so that I don´t have to hardcode year values as tabs titles? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I finally got this to work by adding on my template.php:

```
function YOURTHEME_quicktabs_alter($quicktabs) { 
if ($quicktabs->machine_name == 'YOUR_QTABS_NAME') { 
  $currYear = date('Y'); 
  for ($i = 0; $i <= 3 ; $i++ ) { 
    $yr = ($currYear-$i); 
    $quicktabs->tabs[$i]['title'] = t($yr); 
  } 
}
```

} 
}

Comment: You don't need to add it to a theme; you can add that code in a custom module.